# What happens if I leave-cancel-quit a password manager service/app?

Tags: password

This isn't a purely Apple scenario, but since all my devices are Apple products, I'll have a chance at understanding/using any tech-toned answers.

Question: I've been doing due-diligence in choosing a password manager.  Then it occurred to me: what happens after, say, 14 months and I decide (insert reason) to quit-cancel the service?  All my passwords, from a trivial game site to my banking access are inside this manager. Does the password manager vomit up the dozens of random-generated machine passwords for me to manually copy & paste?  Do I have to go to each site and "create new password"?  The best situation I can conceive is laborious and miserable.  The worst is being left right out in the cold.

The FAQ and Support pages of 1Password, Nordpass, and all the others are very resistant to discussing the idea of someone ever quitting their marvellous service.  The only entries I've found are how to literally uninstall their software, but with no notes on what happens next.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: There is no one answer.  It differs for each nanager

Comment: 1Password can export its items, and is able to import from a few other apps like LastPass. So depending on the your choice, you may be able to move data from one app to another. Like @mmmmmm wrote, it depends on the specific password managers. If you chose not to use one again, you somehow have to get your passwords from the export your app has provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate each password manager.

As an example, 1Password has this support page [Export](https://support.1password.com/export/) which says:

```
Open and unlock 1Password.

Select the vault you want to export. It’s not possible to export from “All Vaults”, so you’ll need to switch to a specific vault.

Choose File > Export > All Items. If you belong to a team account, there may be some vaults where you don’t have the “Export items” permission. Ask your team administrator.

Enter your 1Password account password.

Choose a file format:

 - 1Password Interchange Format (.1pif) to move data to another copy of 1Password. 
 - Comma Delimited Text (.csv) to move data to a different
   app. 
 - Tab Delimited Text (.txt) to move data to a different app.

Click Save.
```

When I try an export, it suggests a 4th file format - csv suited to iCloud Keychain.

Most password managers will import from a .csv, but the transfer may need the file to be massaged somewhat - most likely some moving columns or adding required header line.

So you just need to search the support pages of each password manager to find out how easy it might be to export and import passwords.